# safari extension injected content not loading

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I have 3 scripts in the "Injected Content/End Scripts" section of my extension. Only one particular script is not being injected.

I removed all 3 scripts and injected each one individually, only a particular script is not being loaded via the injected content section while the other two load just fine.

Is there any reason why a particular script might not get injected?

Comment: One script may not be injected because the one before it had errors in it. You should be able to see any script loading errors in the developer tools console in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I had a syntax error in that script that prevented it from being loaded by the safari extension builder.

There doesn't seem to be a way to debug syntax errors in injected scripts other than having your linter on in your editor.